How to fix <anonymous closure> in Flutter?
I'm encountering an issue with an anonymous closure when Socket.IO connects in Flutter. Also when i make http requests i got the same issue.
Error:
I/flutter (26516): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (26516): │ #0   new SocketClient._internal. (package:game/connection/controller/socket_client.dart:25:14)
I/flutter (26516): │ #1   EventEmitter.emit. (package:socket_io_common/src/util/event_emitter.dart:61:14)
I/flutter (26516): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (26516): │  Connected to server
I/flutter (26516): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
class SocketClient {
  Socket? socket;
  static SocketClient? _instance;
  bool isDisconnectDialogVisible = false;

  SocketClient._internal() {
    socket = io(
      dotenv.env['BASE_URL']!,
      OptionBuilder()
          .setTransports(['websocket'])
          .disableAutoConnect()
          .enableForceNew()
          .setExtraHeaders({'token': dotenv.env['SOCKET_TOKEN']!})
          .build(),
    );

    socket!.onConnect((_) {
      logger.i('Connected to server');
    });

    socket!.onDisconnect((_) {
      showDisconnectDialog();
      logger.i('Disconnected from server');
      reconnect();
    });

    socket!.on('error', (data) {
      logger.e('WebSocket error: $data');
      Get.dialog(showConnectionErr(), barrierDismissible: false);
      socket?.disconnect();
      reconnect();
    });

    socket!.connect();
  }

  void showDisconnectDialog() {
    if (!isDisconnectDialogVisible) {
      isDisconnectDialogVisible = true;
      Get.dialog(
        showConnectionErr(),
        barrierDismissible: false,
      ).then((_) {
        isDisconnectDialogVisible = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void reconnect() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
      if (!isDisconnectDialogVisible) {
        socket?.connect();
      } else {
        reconnect(); // If dialog is visible, wait and try again
      }
    });
  }

  static SocketClient get instance {
    _instance ??= SocketClient._internal();
    return _instance!;
  }
}


Edit:
When I switched from using logger() to print(), I didn't encounter the issue. Does this mean the problem lies with the logger itself, or is it not considered a problem?
